# Stateless EJB timer active timer count too high

Tags: java, timer, ejb

I have a stateless EJB version 3.0 running that supposed to fire once every 30 seconds.  My problem is that after I got it running, no matter what I do, it will always run with 4 active timers (verified in my WebLogic console) that go off about every 2 seconds or so.

Sadly, I can't be super specific with my code, but here is what I have:

- A create timer method that I'm calling at the beginning of my program. Here is a timerService.createTimer call. This really doesn't do anything because the timers are still being created without this being called. Why?
- A @postConstruct method that is just printing something out for testing. It's being called like it should.
- A @Timeout method that is being called WAY more than it should because of the multiple timers. This is where my business logic is.
- In my weblogic-ejb-jar.xml I have the max-beans-in-free-pool set to 1

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I think I don't have a full understanding of what's going on, but I can't find anything helpful for this.

Comment: You should detail this part : "A create timer method that I'm calling at the beginning of my program. Here is a timerService.createTimer call."
Change the naming in your code, it should be OK.

Comment: Change the naming as in the method name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In EJB 3.0 all timers are persistent. In other words they survive server restarts.

If you create an interval timer it will run until you cancel it. Stopping the server will not cancel it. Many implementations have been known to try and catch up again when the server is restarted.

Your existing code is creating yet another timer when you restart it.

Consider adding the following to an @PostConstruct method in the EJB that services the Timer:

```
 @Resource
 private TimerService timerService;

 @PostConstruct
 void startup() {
     ...
     for (Timer timer: timerService.getTimers()) {
         timer.cancel();
     }
     ...
 }
```

This should clean things up for you.

Comment: Yup, that was it. Thanks!